# wordpress - posts by category

Tags: wordpress

in wordpress how to display  posts by category in sidebar?

Comment: in the right side of this page, there are around 20 similar questions. and most of them have answers.

Comment: Try to learn `query_posts()` possibilities. It's very simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lists wordpress posts by category and tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197864/lists-wordpress-posts-by-category-and-tag)

Answer (score -1):

1. Try this plugin for listing the category posts as widget for your
   sidebar.

[Category Posts Widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/category-posts/screenshots/)

```
                               [OR]


<?php query_posts('category_name=your-category-name&showposts=5&order=asc'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<h2 class="head1"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>   
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```